# How to correctly use Keep-Alive header with libcurl C++ library

Tags: visual-c++, libcurl, c++98

I have an application with makes millions of call to a backend server to fetch some data from the database. It uses HTTP API with TCP and the average time taken to execute a request is 150-200ms. The time spent on the backend server is merely 1-2ms. A lot of time is spent on making the DNS Lookup and the Three-way SSL handshake.
I would like to utilize the TCP `Keep-Alive` functionality to not close the TCP Connections to the backend.
I have noticed that merely adding the headers for the requests reduced the time taken to execute the requests. This was noticed via POSTMAN.

However, I don't see similar data when executed via our C++ application.

Below is the code that we use.

```
INT CCurlHTTP::HTTPSPost(const CString& endPointUrl, const CString& urlparam,const CString& cookie){
    
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    CString KeepAlive = "Connection: keep-alive";
    CString KeepAliveSettings = "Keep-Alive: timeout=100, max=100";

    get_request req;
    req.buffer =0;
    req.len =0;
    req.buflen =0;

    if(curl) 
    {
        //add url, headers, and paramaters to the request
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, endPointUrl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_httpHeadAccept);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_httpContentType);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, KeepAlive);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, KeepAliveSettings);
        //callback function used to save response
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_String);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 5L);
        req.buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
        req.buflen = CHUNK_SIZE;
        req.len = 0;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&req);
        
        if (!cookie.IsEmpty())
        {
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_DBAuthCertficate); //What is difference between this and line no 118?
            CString pCookie = "DBAuthTicket=" + cookie;
            curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_COOKIE, pCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            headers = curl_slist_append(headers, m_OAuthToken);
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlparam);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        errbuf[0] = 0;
        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512000);
        CFileTime start, end;
                CFileTimeSpan duration;

        start = CFileTime::GetCurrentTime();

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        end = CFileTime::GetCurrentTime();
        duration = (end - start);

        CString elapsed, logMsg;
        elapsed.Format("%ld",duration.GetTimeSpan()/10000);
        logMsg.Format("[CCurlHTTP::HTTPSPost::%d]Respone time = %s ms",__LINE__, elapsed);
        UTHelper::Get().WriteLog(logMsg);

        long res_code;
        
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &res_code);

        if(res_code != 200 && res_code != 201)
        {
            res = CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR;
        }

        m_response = (char*)req.buffer;
        m_errDescription.Format("%ld", res_code);
        len = req.len;
        buflen = req.buflen;

        //curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        free(req.buffer);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This piece of code is used by Single threaded application as well as multi-threaded Web application (VBScript + C++ COM DLL) It is a very legacy codebase.

Questions

1. We create a new CurlHTTP class everytime we want to execute a new request. Will curl_easy_init give us new curl handles everytime or will it give out the same ones.
2. How do I make this work with `Keep-Alive` headers. The same code has not affect with these headers at all. The response times are still 150-200 ms.
3. Please help in any way possible. I cannot make CurlHTTP singleton since this code is also used in a multi-threaded environment and it could cause bottleneck if I try synchronization.
4. Where do I initialize curl_global_init and what params should I pass there.

LEGACY CODE - C++ 98 + VC7.

Comment: libcurl automatically reuses connections by default - if you keep using the same `CURL` handle. The code shown creates a new handle for every request (and moreover, leaks it), so the library has to negotiate a new connection from scratch. Of course `curl_easy_init` allocates a new handle every time it's called - for all it knows, you want to issue multiple requests in parallel. It can't know you simply leaked previous handle and don't plan to use it anymore.

Comment: Re: `curl_global_init`. A reasonable place for this call would be in `main` (or whatever your application's entry point is), and a reasonable parameter would be `CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT`, as the name implies.

Comment: How do I re-use the same curl handle? Should I declare the clasd as Singleton? If I do so, it will definitely affect when this code is put in a multithreaded environment. Please guide me here

Comment: I don't know enough about your design to recommend how you should manage your connections. You can't send multiple requests over the same connection simultaneously, so one way or another, you would need to decide when it's OK to reuse a connection and when it's necessary to create a new one. Once you spell out these conditions, it will become clear how to manage `CURL` handles in order to satisfy them.